# Как правильно обработать onClick для RecyclerView?

Tags: android

Я написал в самом адаптере к `RecyclerView` `onClick`, но получается что действие передается на каждый 15-ый элемент... В чем проблема? И как мне после нажатия  на `CardView` грамотно подтянуть ещё данные по Id элементу класса `DataForecast.DataBean` и впихнуть? Спасибо

```
public class ForecastAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ForecastAdapter.ForecastViewHolder> {

private List<DataForecast.DataBean> list;

public ForecastAdapter(List<DataForecast.DataBean> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

private List<GetDescriptionForecastModel> descrption;

@Override
public ForecastViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_forecast, parent, false);
    return new ForecastViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ForecastViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DataForecast.DataBean searchModel = list.get(position);        
    holder.timedate.setText(searchModel.getDate());
    holder.game.setText(searchModel.getCommand());
    holder.forecast.setText("Фора1 по очкам (-4.5) @ " + searchModel.getKf());
    //GetDescriptionForecastModel searchDescription = descrption.get(position); -- это дополнительные данные из другого класса которые мне нужны после onClick
    //holder.about.setText(searchDescription.getData());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class ForecastViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView timedate, game, forecast, score, about;
    CardView cv_forecast;
    public ForecastViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        timedate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_forecast_timedate);
        game = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_forecast_game);
        forecast = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_forecast_forecast);
        score = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_forecast_score);
        about = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.forecast_txt_about);
        cv_forecast = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_forecast);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View cardView = (View)itemView.findViewById(R.id.forecast_cardview_all);
        if (about.getVisibility()==View.GONE) {
            about.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.forecast_about_all);
            //TODO здесь делаю видимым поле для данных после onClick

        }else if (about.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
            about.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае не вижу причины переносить слушатель нажатий в класс-холдер. Назначьте слушатель нажатий в `onBindViewHolder`, тем более, что там у вас и прочие данные есть

Comment: подскажите как поставить слушатель в onBindViewHolder?

Comment: Точно также как для обычной View. Просто `someView.setOnClickListener(...);`

Comment: извините пожалуйста, но я не могу слушатель самостоятельно выставить...я только начинаю программировать. Если бы Вы могли кинуть как оно должно выглядеть в моем коде буду очень признателен(пробую holder.setOnClickListener(...) и не получается)

Comment: @ТарасЖупник, holder - не View, потому и не получается. Вешайте слушатель на View. например так: `holder.cv_forecast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ public void onClick(View v){Log.d("TAG", "НАЖАТО");}});`